# How to pass the id of Div as an argument to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Div that is dynamically added to a page with the click of a button using jQuery.

I would like to be able to remove the Div with the click of the cross-button.png using the `RemoveArtist()` function.

```
$("<div class=\"input-append\" id=\"artist"
    + artists.length - 1 + "\" ><label style=\"background-color:#e0ffff\">"
    + artistVal + "</label><img onclick=\"RemoveArtist()\" id=\"removeartist\""
    + " src=\"/Content/bootstrap/img/cross-button.png\" /></div>")
    .appendTo(addDiv);
```

The remove artist fucntion should look like this:

```
var RemoveArtist = function (div,artistlength) {

    $('div').remove();
    artists.splice(artistlength, 1);
};
```

How can I pass the actual div to the `RemoveArtist`  function and also the `artistlength` which is the `artists.length - 1` value from the Div?

So basically I am trying to delete the Div and remove the artist from the artists array.

Comment: Just an advice: if you're using jQuery, don't use the traditional event registering. Use jQuery for that. So no `onclick` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you'd be better of if you created actual elements instead of a string.
It's more stuff to write, but makes everyhing a lot easier to keep track of :

```
var input_append = $('<div />', {id: 'artist' + (artists.length - 1)}),
    label        = $('<label />', {style: 'background-color:#e0ffff',
                                   text : artistVal
                                  }
                    ),
    image        = $('<img />', {id:  'removeartist',
                                 src: '/Content/bootstrap/img/cross-button.png',
                                 on: {
                                       click: function() {
                                          input_append.remove();
                                          artists.splice(artists.length - 1, 1);
                                       }
                                     }
                                }
                    );

addDiv.append( input_append.append(label, img) );
```

Comment: +1 but it looks a bit too much :) I'd use just `on.click` for the image, the rest can be placed in the string IMO.

Comment: @MaxArt - sure, there are easier ways to do this, but moving away from HTML strings and start using actual elements with jQuery objects or `document.createElement` will, in my opinion, make the code and the coder better, and it's just so much easier to read once you get used to it.

Comment: Everything works except artists.splice(artists.length - 1, 1);

Comment: @Milligran - I'm not really sure what that is supposed to do, but passing a negative index would start from the end of the array, so `.splice(-1, 1)` probably does the same thing as your use of length, and the array is most likely modified, but if you're expecting the ID of the div to change, that won't happen as the number is passed by reference, and doesn't change when the array changes ?